# Weak topology on the space of germs of holomorphic funtions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(\mathcal{O},\tau_{ind})$ denote the space of germs of all  $\mathbb{C}$-valued-holomorphic functions at 0 equipped with the inductive topology which turns it into a Silva/DFS-space (i.e. it is the inductive limit of a sequence of Banach spaces, with compact linking maps). Another description of $\mathcal{O}$ is that it is the ring of all power series which converge locally at 0. $(\mathcal{O},\tau_{ind})$ is isomorphic (as LCVS) to the strong dual of $(\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C}),\tau_{co})$ - the space of entire functions equipped with the compact-open topology, which can be also described as a power series space (see for example the introductory book on functional analysis by Meise and Vogt). The duality is $<a,\phi> := \sum a_{n} \phi_{n}$.
For $\phi = \sum \phi_{n} x^{n} \in  \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ let $p_{\phi}(\sum_{n \in N} a_{n} x^{n}):= \sum \vert \phi_{n} a_{n} \vert$. The system $\{p_{\phi} \mid \phi \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})\}$ then generates the inductive topology on $\mathcal{O}$.
My question: Does $(\mathcal{O},\tau_{ind})$ carry the weak topology? I.e. is it true that a net $(f_{i})_{i\in I}$ converges to 0 in $(\mathcal{O},\tau_{co})$ iff $<f_{i}-f,\phi>$ converges to 0 for all $\phi \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$.
Note a sequence converges in $(\mathcal{O},\tau_{ind})$ iff it converges weakly, since $(\mathcal{O},\tau_{ind})$ is a Montel-space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is---no.  One way to see this is to use the fact that this space with the weak topology is not complete but every Silva space is.  The only situation where a result of this kind can hold is the special one of a Silva space which is the inductive limit of finite dimensional spaces, essentially the space of finite sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I know that Silva spaces are complete, but how do you see that $\mathcal{O}$ equipped with the weak topology is incomplete? Can you give me some reference on this?

Comment: In fact, the strong dual of Frechet-space $E$ never carries the weak topology, unless $E$ is finite-dimensional (see the article "When $(E,\sigma (E, E')) $ is a $ DF $-space?" by D. Krassowska.